# Entire function that is in $\mathcal{L}^1({\mathbb R^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I take the lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ .
Take $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ a continuous function and $\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|\mathrm d\mu(x)<\infty$.

Can we say any thing about  $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}|f(x)|$ ? or can we say if $f$ is bounded ?

If we can show $f$ is bounded can we generalize this result to $\mathbb R^n$.

---

Basically I was dealing with a different problem .

It said "If $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a holomorphic function and $\int_{\mathbb R^2}|f(x+iy)|\mathrm dx\mathrm dy <\infty$ then $f\equiv0$".

So my approach was if I can show $f$ is bounded then I am done.

Thanks in advance please help me out and let me know if I am wrong at my approach.

Comment: continuous and $L^1$ does not mean bounded, sadly. You can take a sum of gaussian densities centered on the naturals, rescaled to have integral $2^{-n}$, and with fastly decreasing variance

Comment: apply Cauchy theorem to bound $f$ in terms of the integral on a circle around it and then integrate that once more to bound $f$ in terms of the double integral and conclude - the result depends on properties of holomorphic (harmonic works too) functions

Comment: Use Liouville's theorem for your second problem. And nothing can be said for the first one.

Comment: For the second one if I can show that it is bounded then only I can apply Lioville's theorem @nicomezi

Comment: @Conrad I didn't get your argument could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Exodd thanks for that counter example

Comment: put it as an answer as it gets too long for a comment

Comment: Maybe change the title, now that the discussion is about the holomorphic question.

Comment: Done it ! @GEdgar

Comment: Boundedness is enforced by the integrability condition. But I agree there is one more argument to find. @Noobmathematician

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by Cauchy $2\pi i f(z)=\int_{|w-z|=R}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw=\int_0^{2\pi}f(z+Re^{it})idt$ so $2\pi|f(z)|\le \int_0^{2\pi}|f(z+Re^{it})|dt$; integrating from say $R=1$ to $R=2$ we get (using that $dxdy=RdRdt \ge dRdt=dtdR, R \ge 1$)

$2\pi|f(z)|\le \int_1^2\int_0^{2\pi}|f(z+Re^{it})|dtdR \le \int_1^2\int_0^{2\pi}|f(z+Re^{it})|RdtdR \le \int \int_{A_z} |f(x+iy)|dxdy \le M $

where $A_z$ is the annulus centered at $z$ between circles of radiuses $1$ and $2$ and $M= \int_{\mathbb R^2}|f(x+iy)|\mathrm dx\mathrm dy <\infty$

so $f$ is constant and hence zero by the finite integral property

As noted in the comments, the same proof works for $f$ harmonic as the integral mean value property is still true as is the fact that a bounded harmonic function in the plane (even bounded one way if the function is real) is constant